# SmartSheet Java API getSheet but only some of the rows

Tags: java, smartsheet-api

I am using the SmartSheet API (Java SDK) in an app that is used internally by my company, and have found that the initial start up of the app is taking longer and longer. I have concluded that at least part of that delay is both getting the entire sheet from SmartSheet and then filtering out all of the rows I have previously processed. Is there a way for me to get everything except those rows that I have already processed? I have a "store number" column in SmartSheet and could feed in a list of stores that I have already processed to filter the list.

But as far as I can tell there is no way to do this. Am I wrong? If so, how do I do this?

I have found the [SmartShet API docs](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#get-sheet), but they do not clearly explain how to use the includes and excludes optional parameters. All of the SmartSheet examples I can find set both values to null. I was hoping that excludes would give me a way to exclude the rows that I know I have processed, but I cannot find clear documentation on how to use this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unfortunately not possible to query sheet data using the Smartsheet API like you would query a table in a database -- i.e., there's no API request you can issue that would function like `SELECT * FROM Sheet WHERE store_number NOT IN (1, 3, 5)`.

In general, the `include` and `exclude` parameters provide a way to make the response larger (i.e., use the `include` parameter to return more data than would normally be returned by default) or smaller (i.e., use the `exclude` parameter to *not return* data that would normally be returned by default). For example, attachment metadata won't be included by default -- but if you specify the `?include=attachments` parameter on the request, it will be included.

Specifying the `exclude=filteredOutRows` parameter allows you to influence  which rows are returned in the response -- but for this parameter to fulfill the scenario you've described, the sheet would have to have a filter currently applied which filters out the rows you don't want to be returned. Seems doubtful that this would be true in your scenario (and it doesn't seem possible to programmatically set/update sheet filters via API), so this doesn't seem particularly useful for you.

** UPDATING TO ADD INFO ABOUT REPORTS **

One other option you might consider. You could manually create a Report (i.e., via the Smartsheet UI) that queries the sheet, and specify criteria for that report which excludes the specified set of store numbers from the report results. Then you could change your app such that it [gets data via the Report](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#get-report) instead of getting data directly from the Sheet. The only catch here is that it's not possible to create or update Reports via the Smartsheet API -- so you'd have to create the Report manually (via the Smartsheet UI), and then periodically update the report manually (via the Smartsheet UI) to add additional store numbers that you want to exclude from the results. Not ideal, but depending on the volume of data you're trying to exclude from the response, and how often the set of store numbers to exclude changes, this approach may be viable for you.

Comment: Kim, thanks for the confirmation - I was afraid that this would be the case. Unfortunately, the data changes too often to make the report option useful.